# Any suggestions on getting consistent recognition of 5'11" as @sys.unit-length?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I need to recognize statements such as the following as a height parameter ( @sys.unit-length):

My client is 5'11" 
Client is 5 ft 11 in

When the height is entered as ft and in it works almost flawlessly. However, when height is entered as 6'2" Api.ai fails to recognize it as a @sys.unit-length entity 50% of the time. I've entered fifty examples in an attempt to train, without improvement.

Any suggestions on how to overcome this problem or a better way to setup an entity to handle it?

Comment: What code are you currently using?

Comment: I'm not using a custom entity. Just the system entity @sys.unit-length. I have started getting more consistent results by continued training.